# Xamarin Calender using PCL

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am looking for a calender in Xamarin Form PCL. After several hours of research I am able to develop one Calander using  **XAMForms.Controls.Calender**    but look and feel is not same.

I need calender with events as shown in attached Image.[image]

Comment: Enhance your question by providing code. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

On GitHub there are some plugin

[XamForms.Controls.Calendar](https://github.com/rebeccaXam/XamForms.Controls.Calendar)

```
new Calendar
{
  BorderColor = Color.Gay,
  BorderWidth = 3,
  BackgroundColor = Color.Gay,
  StartDay = DayOfWeek.Sunday,
  StartDate = DateTime.Now
}
```

[TheAlmightyBob/Calendars](https://github.com/TheAlmightyBob/Calendars)

[rid00z/Xamarin.Forms.Calendar](https://github.com/rid00z/Xamarin.Forms.Calendar)

```
public class SampleCalendarPage : ContentPage 
{
    CalendarView _calendarView;
    StackLayout _stacker;

    public SampleCalendarPage ()
    {
        Title = "Calendar Sample";

        _stacker = new StackLayout ();
        Content = _stacker;

        _calendarView = new CalendarView() {
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand
        };
        _stacker.Children.Add (_calendarView);
        _calendarView.DateSelected += (object sender, DateTime e) =&gt; {
            _stacker.Children.Add(new Label() 
                { 
                    Text = "Date Was Selected" + e.ToString("d"),
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                });
        };

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An option I've been using is the [ComponentOne](https://www.componentone.com/Xamarin/default.aspx) Calendar. This has templating support for the daypart of the calendar so you can create any look and feel you want for the day cells. It is not free though.